# Creating an array of structs in a function at runtime

Tags: c, pointers

First, apologies since undoubtedly this information exists on SO, but I'm having trouble tracking it down.

Trying (and failing) to wrap my brain around some pointer magic I'd like to do. At runtime I'd like to create an "array" of structs that I can iterate through.

```
typedef struct  {
    int length;
    const char* location;
} receipt_info;

void testA()
{
    receipt_info *receipts;
    testB(&receipts);
    printf("Receipt 0 length: %i\n", receipts[0].length); // Displays valid value
    printf("Receipt 1 length: %i\n", receipts[1].length); // Displays invalid value
}

void testB(receipt_info **info)
{
    *info = malloc(sizeof(receipt_info) * 2);
    info[0]->length = 100;
    info[1]->length = 200;
}
```

In this example, I've hardcoded it to 2, but IRL it will be determined by external factors.

What should I be doing differently here?

Comment: OT: Why do you name the same thing differently (`receipt` vs. `info`)? Such nameing does *not* improve readbilitly. Stick to capitalising types and using lower cases for variables. Like `typedef ... Receipe_info;` which allows you to use a variable like  `Receipe_info receipe_info;` And even further indicate pointers like for example `Receipe_info * preceipe_info;` and `Receipe_info ** ppreceipe_info;` The last rule might have helped you *seeing* your mistake just by looking at your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part wont work -- you are doing two dereferences, but in the wrong order

```
info[0]->length = 100;
info[1]->length = 200;
```

Needs to be

```
(*info)[0].length = 100;
(*info)[1].length = 200;
```

Comment: I owe you a beer for that one. ;) Thanks!